# How to get the local ip of eth0 using C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I want to find either the IP address of eth0 in local network (if the cable is pluged-in) or return the loopback IP (127.0.0.1) otherwise. So, I tried the following code:

```
struct in_addr getCurrentIP() {
    int fd=0;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct in_addr IP;
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0) {
        perror("SIOCGIFFLAGS");}
    if ((ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_UP)){
        ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
        close(fd);
        IP = ((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr;
    } else {
        close(fd);
        inet_aton ("127.0.0.1",&IP);
    }
    return  IP;
}
```

This code works fine until I plug-out my Ethernet cable. Then, it returns **arbitrary IP**.

PS I am connected to a network which provides dynamic IPs (i.e. using DHCP).

Comment: You might need to query the actual state (_linked_), before bindig to it.

Comment: you are right, this is what i am trying to do in the if-else statement. I tried to check IFF_RUNNING by using: if ((ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_UP & IFF_RUNNING)), and the same thing for IFF_POINTOPOINT but it returns always false (i.e. redirects to the loopback in both cases).

Comment: Consider using popen() to run ifconfig.  Normally, Ubuntu reports 10 config lines for eth0, and 9 lines for lo.  Each section contains "inet addr" and some state info about the link.  After link goes down, the 2nd line of eth0 ifconfig section no longer has the inet addr (but the lo inet addr is still reported).

Comment: yes @DOUGLASO.MOEN, this could be done. The second line is always for IPV4 address. But there should be much better solution. The supposed solution would be more reliable.

Comment: What should the code do if eth0 has multiple IP addresses? What if the machine has an active eth1 but an inactive eth0?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, my function should cover such cases. But at the mean time, I am not interested in handling several IP addresses/several interfaces. In my case, there is only one IP address on "eth0".

Comment: As you do not tell us which for platfrom you are trying to achieve this: Does your system provide `getifaddrs()` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)?

Comment: Nitpicking; For an interface, is/are there any other IP-address but the "*local*" one/s?

Comment: Dear @alk, indeed i don't want to use ifaddr because I have just one interface and ip. Any way thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, this is the solution:

```
struct in_addr getCurrentIP() {
    int fd=0;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct in_addr IP;
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0) {
        perror("SIOCGIFFLAGS");}
    if ((ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_UP) && (ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_RUNNING)){
        ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
        close(fd);
        IP = ((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr;
    } else {
        close(fd);
        inet_aton ("127.0.0.1",&IP);
    }
    return  IP;
}
```

I would like to thank you for your help.